# my DataGridView is blank after setting DataSource for it

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a function that gets a **DataGridView** as parameter and export its data into excel:

```
public Worksheet exportToExcel(DataGridView dgv)
```

I want to do the same action on **DataTable**, so I wrote the following function:

```
public Worksheet exportToExcel(System.Data.DataTable dataTable)
{
    DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView();
    dgv.DataSource = dataTable;
    return exportToExcel(dgv);
}
```

But when I run the second function, **DataGridView** doesn't have any column and row. 
I'm sure that my **DataTable** has data and when I show the **DataGridView** on a form, everything is ok.

Here is my **exportToExcel** function:

```
public Worksheet exportToExcel(DataGridView dgv)
{
    //create excel application
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelApplication = new ApplicationClass();
    excelApplication.Visible = false;

    //open excel template file
    object template = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Reports/Excel/General.xltx";
    Workbook excelWorkbook = excelApplication.Workbooks.Add(template);
    Worksheet excelWorksheet = (Worksheet)excelWorkbook.Worksheets.get_Item("Sheet1");

    //exporting column headers
    for (int i = 0; i < dgv.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        excelWorksheet.Cells[1, i + 1] = dgv.Columns[i].HeaderText;
    }

    //exporting data
    for (int i = 0; i < dgv.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < dgv.Columns.Count; j++)
        {
            excelWorksheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = dgv.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value;
        }
    }

    //draw border for each cell
    Range range = excelWorksheet.get_Range("A1", excelWorksheet.Cells[dgv.Rows.Count + 1, dgv.Columns.Count]);
    range.Borders[XlBordersIndex.xlInsideHorizontal].LineStyle = XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;
    range.Borders[XlBordersIndex.xlInsideVertical].LineStyle = XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;
    range.BorderAround(Type.Missing, XlBorderWeight.xlThick, XlColorIndex.xlColorIndexAutomatic, Type.Missing);

    //resize columns automatically based on their data
    excelWorksheet.Columns.AutoFit();

    //show excel application
    excelApplication.Visible = true;

    return excelWorksheet;
}
```

Comment: I think DataGridView doesn't refresh its data while it is hidden.

Comment: have you tried calling `dgv.Refresh()` ?

Comment: If you already have a table, why the datagridview if your not displaying it anyways. This is bad implementation, use the datatable you have and export it to excel...

Comment: Also in your return you recalling that function and passing a datagridview instead of a datatable... this won't work or nevertheless compile...

Comment: @Veland: Yes, I tried it but it doesn't work yet.

Comment: @Mr CoDeXeR: I have some forms with DataGridView in them. So I use this function for exporting their data. Sometimes I want to export DataTable to excel so I think that I can use the same function.

Comment: You can with different arguments...

Comment: I can't see how it wouldn't work the way you're using it. Show more code from exportToExcel maybe?

Comment: @JWiley: I edited my question and placed exportToExcel function in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"when I show the DataGridView on a form, everything is ok"

In order to read (iterate) the rows/columns of a datagridview it needs to be added to a control (Form/UserControl). I thought that it also needed to be drawn, but this is not the case.
This means that you can add the DataGridView to a new form before calling exportToExcel, and then Dispose the Form and DataGridView.

```
public Worksheet exportToExcel(System.Data.DataTable dataTable)
{
    //Wrap in using statements to make sure controls are disposed
    using (Form frm = new Form())
    {
        using(DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView())
        {   
            //Add dgv to form before setting datasource                             
            frm.Controls.Add(dgv);  
            dgv.DataSource = dataTable;   
            return exportToExcel(dgv);
        }
    }   
}
```

This should work, but I would like to point out that this is not a solution I would recomend. I would create a exportToExcel method
that takes a DataTable as an argument.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried your code but it doesn't work too.

Comment: See my edit, try adding the DataGridView to the form before setting the datasource